# String to Boolean.parseBooelan

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a boolean function that returns true or false.

```
private boolean isExist(Optional<List<Attributes>> attributes) {
        
    if (attributes.get().stream().filter(att -> att.getAttributeName().equals("exist") && att.getAttributeValue().equals("true")).count() > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

How can I make use of `Boolean.parseBoolean` instead `att.getAttributeValue().equals("true")`? Is there any advantage of using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
if (attributes.isEmpty()) {
    return false;
}
return attributes.get().stream().anyMatch(att ->
        "exist".equals(att.getAttributeName()) &&
        Boolean.parseBoolean(att.getAttributeValue())
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can (and should) map the `Optional` directly in case it's empty. Then you can pass `Boolean.parseBoolean` as a parameter to map.

```
return attributes.map(Attributes::stream)
    .filter (att -> "exist".equals (att.getAttributeName())) 
    .map (Attribute::GetValue) 
    .map (Boolean::parseBoolean)
  .orElse (false);
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make use of Boolean.parseBoolean instead
> att.getAttributeValue().equals("true")?

You can do it as follows:

```
private boolean isExist(Optional<Attributes> attributes)
{    
    if (attributes.get().stream().filter(att -> att.getAttributeName().equals("exist") && Boolean.parseBoolean(att.getAttributeValue())==true)).count() > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm curious to know what is the advantage of using Boolean.parse boolean against not using it.

Comment: parsing it from String to boolean will make you avoid typo mistakes like writing treu instead of true, but I don't see other benefits

Comment: The only advantage is you would be using a tried-and-tested library function rather than something you've crafted yourself (though obviously it would be pretty hard to get something so trivial wrong in this case!)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your optional first:

```
private boolean isExist(Optional<List<Attributes>> attributes) {
    return attributes.map(list -> list.stream().anyMatch(YourClass::isMatch))
                     .orElse(false);
}
private static boolean isMatch(Attributes att) {
    return att.getAttributeName().equals("exist") && Boolean.parseBoolean(att.getAttributeValue());
}
```

Because you are only interested on a single match you should use the `anyMatch`.

> How can I make use of Boolean.parseBoolean instead att.getAttributeValue().equals("true")?
> Is there any advantage of using it?

Yes,

> public static boolean parseBoolean(String s) Parses the string
> argument as a boolean. The boolean returned represents the value true
> if the string argument is not null and is equal, *ignoring case, to the
> string "true"*.

With this method strings like "TruE" will be consider true, so you do not have to worry about upper and lower case stuff, and more important if you receive a null Boolean.parseBoolean(..) return False. Nevertheless, I think in your case, unless you have a good reason to not do it, the better option would actually be to change

```
att.getAttributeValue()
```

to return true of false instead of a String encoding a boolean.